# How to install Oracle 10g Express and 11g Enterprise on same machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-10g

I have to continue maintaining an Oracle 8i database that receives information (about 20 Inserts and Updates a day) from a 9i database.  I am upgrading the 9i database to 11g which does not support database links to 8i.

The plan is to link from Oracle 11g to Oracle 10 XE and then to the 8i and hope that one day I won't have to do this.

I have already found articles noting that installing XE after any other version is not recommended.

Has anyone installed XE and another Oracle version side by side?  What order was used and what problems were encountered?

Edit: @George3 [some forum posts](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=886065) indicate that you can use JDBC drivers to connect 11g and 8i.  Please add some detail and post it as answer.

Comment: Could a regularly scheduled job using JDBC take data from  staging table(s) on 11g and insert/update 8i instead?

Comment: What about setting up a VM for 10XE?  Or must these run on the same machine?

Comment: It's easier if they run on the same machine.  It could be done with a regular 10g and 11i so it seems possible with express.

Comment: @George3 I'm not sure whether you've seen the edit for you in this post.  Could you answer that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't need to worry too much.

Install XE first.  You don't get to choose the database name (XE) or the port (1521).
Next, install 11g to the default app folder.
Modify the TNSNAMES.ora files for both databases so they know about each other.  Test connections and create database links and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a script on the 8i database that exports the data to a flat file? Then copy those flat files to the 11g database to import them?

Comment: I could create a folder on the 8i machine and then map that as a directory for the 11g database and then write csv files to it but this is not an optimal solution. You would need extra tables to log what was entered.  Unfortunately I have views of tables on the 8i database that I did not mention that are used for other transactions on the 11g.